# User push notifications in cordova 3.3

Tags: android, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, google-cloud-messaging, cordova-3

I want to implement notifications in android using 3.3 cordova, I'm new at this. I have tried several tutorials but without success. Could explain a simple way to implement it step by step?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cordova Push Notifications Plugin for Android, iOS and WP8

*This plugin is for use with Cordova, and allows your application to receive push notifications on both Android and iOS devices. The Android implementation uses [Google's GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) service](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html), whereas the iOS version is based on Apple [APNS Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html).*

**Follow the given step by step**

**1) [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)**

**2) [Implement Push Notifications in your PhoneGap Application](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/)**

**Note:** *Dont't forget to add cordova_plugin.js and PushNotification.js file in your page.*

Answer (score 1):

Use this phonegap plugin for push notification both in Android and IOS. It works fine for me.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

Answer (score 0):

You can copy/paste the instruction on this link .

https://github.com/Pushwoosh/phonegap-3-sample-app

The files you need are : copy the index.js , to add pushnotification.js into your index.html , to add the plug in pushwoosh to config.xml and the important thing is API ID from google and the ID from pushwoosh , those two ID you can put in the index.js for IOS and Android .