# GitHub phonegap-ua-push project hosted on Shared Windows?

Tags: android, ios, git, github, push

I'm new to `PhoneGap`.

I just downloaded `PhoneGap example` from GitHub ( https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push ) to send push notifications to my users.

Question: As it is all about html and javascript, could I simply host this project on my `Godaddy Windows Shared` account and still benefit from the push notification feature to use on `iOS` and `Android`?

Thanks

Comment: See the link for push notification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234573/user-push-notifications-in-cordova-3-3/23243014#23243014

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I'm asking.
My question is: Can Upload this project on a Windows Shared hosting account?